# Which structure is represented in this video (if any)?

Tags: galaxy, universe

I know this is not supposed to be precise since it is just a movie but I would suppose it is based on real things. In the Contact movie intro
https://youtu.be/EWwhQB3TKXA?t=1m I think the Milk Way is shown at around 2:12, I am wondering what is the structure shown around 2:32. Does that a representation of anything real? Virgo maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is supposed to be a representation of the Centaurus A/M83 Galaxy group.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centaurus_A/M83_Group

These are a bunch of galaxies between 12 million and 15 million light years away.

The big central dust lane in Cen A is very recognisable.

I guess the sequence then continues through the Virgo cluster and supercluster which are roughly in the same direction.